# How to update in laravel with multidimensional array with one row

Tags: laravel

All of my data are stored on a multidimensional array and I want to use laravel update with only one line of code without using any loop on every update.

If there is a code like this when inserting multiple data in laravel.

```
$applicants_insert_data = [[
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'sample1',
     'contact' => '09123456789',
     'email' => sample@sample.com,
],[
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'sample2',
     'contact' => '09987654321',
     'email' => sample2@sample2.com,
]]; 

applicants::insert($applicants_insert_data);
```

Is it possible or any way that I can use that kind of method in updating my data?

like this:

```
$applicants_update_data = [[
     'name' => 'sample1',
     'contact' => '09123456789',
     'email' => sample@sample.com,
],[
     'name' => 'sample2',
     'contact' => '09987654321',
     'email' => sample2@sample2.com,
]]; 

$applicants_id = [[
     'id' => 1
],[
     'id' => 2,
]];

applicants::find($applicants_id)->update($applicants_update_data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not available out of the box in Laravel. However, there is a third party package that allows this type of functionality:

https://packagist.org/packages/mavinoo/laravel-batch

From the examples posted in the docs:

```
$table = 'users';

$value = [
     [
         'id' => 1,
         'status' => 'active',
         'nickname' => 'Mohammad'
     ] ,
     [
         'id' => 5,
         'status' => 'deactive',
         'nickname' => 'Ghanbari'
     ] ,
];

$index = 'id';


Batch::update($table, $value, $index);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll Check it right away. I'll update you If there is any prob.

Comment: Hi Jiromas. That looks like a great suggestion by Peter however if you look at the code it loops through array of values.

Comment: Looks to me like the loop is just building up the single SQL string of values, then it gets executed in one query.

Comment: @Peter Hi! I just tested it and it worked perfectly as I want to.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: @Josh As long as it's not using any queries every loop it's fine for me. As peter said, it creates a string of SQL and putting it on a single query which is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Great then it should be a perfect solution for you

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril if you mark the answer as accepted it will let others know that it solved your particular user case.